# Countries like (Barreiras - Brazil,Mashhad - Iran) timezone abbrevation is coming as -03,+330 instead as BRT and IRST

Tags: javascript

Abrrevation of timezone is not coming for some countries.

for india abbrevation is IST it is ok but for other countries like Brazil instead of getting BRT I am getting -30

```
var rightNow = new Date();
alert(String(String(rightNow).split("(")[1]).split(")")[0]);

output. +330 for IRAN instead of IRST
```

Instead of getting numbers I need names for any country.

Comment: From MDN: "An implementation dependent string representation of the timezone, which might be an abbreviation or full name (there is no standard for names or abbreviations of timezones), e.g. 'Line Islands Time' or 'LINT'" and "Until ECMAScript 2018 (edition 9), the format of the string returned by `Date.prototype.toString` was implementation dependent. Therefore it should not be relied upon to be in the specified format." You should not rely on this; use the wonderful [Moment/TZ](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) library instead, which includes the TZ database.

Comment: I tried with moment in the following way const timeZone = moment.tz.guess();
    const time = new Date();
    const timeZoneOffset = time.getTimezoneOffset();moment.tz.zone(timeZone).abbr(timeZoneOffset); it is also working for only few countries but not for all countries as mentioned above

Comment: For some reason, IANA timezone list (which is the ultimate authority on the internet regarding time zone information) never mentions IRST. You might want to ask with tags [tag:timezone] and [tag:iana] as to why that is.

Comment: thanks for the info but if I need abbrevation for any country how should I proceed.Even if they are not present in IANA.

Comment: No idea, since you seem to want information that is not normally available. Javascript does not have this information; you would need a database that has this info. I'll remind you once again you are asking a question meant for _timezone specialists_ in _javascript tag_. That's like going to a New York cake baking school to ask questions about sugar cane production in Ecuador. Sure it has some contact points, but the experts you're looking for are elsewhere. Tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in IANA there is no such information in the latest database.